# Selenium Click when onclick="return false;"'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In web page,there are few tabs like <kbd>Customer</kbd><kbd>Account</kbd><kbd>Contact</kbd>.
These tabs are inside `SPAN` html tag.

PFB, the html source code for accounts tab:

```html
<a class="x-tab-right" onclick="return false;" href="#">
    <em class="x-tab-left">
        <span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
            <span class="x-tab-strip-text ">
                Account
            </span>
        </span>
    </em>
</a>
```

I have tried the below **click methods** apart from the normal click,but none worked:

1.`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);`

2.
`Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
        builder.moveToElement(we).click().perform();`

In **QTP**, using device reply I was able to click on the tab as **that it stimulated the mouse click method**

**Please suggest on how to stimulate the mouse click and click the 'Accounts' tab**

Comment: Please post whole html source !

Comment: How do you locate `we`? How did you try the "normal click"? Do you have an error when trying to click?

Comment: Can't you just use driver.findElement(By...("..").click(); ?

Comment: I am using page object model.
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[.='Account']")
private WebElement tabAccount;

tabAccount.click();

Comment: "none worked" ... could you tell us what the actual error/stacktrace is?

Comment: If we check the existence of element using visibility,clickable..it will return true..
since the object exists in applications,there won't be any error/ stack trace..